# Cant solve error: #<Double (anonymous)> received unexpected message :[]= with (:rule_code, 1)

Tags: ruby, rspec

Im a struggling to solve the above error i get when testing the following:

```
def add_rule_code new_rule
  count = list[:multiple_item_rules].count + list[:total_price_rules].count + 1
  new_rule[:rule_code] = count
end
```

with the following test:

```
  it "adds a unique rule code" do
    item_rule = double( {rule_type: "item", item_code: 001, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50} )
    rules.add_rule_code item_rule
    expect(rules.list[:multiple_item_rules][:rule_code]).to eq 1
  end
```

I get the following error message:

```
1) Promotional_Rules New rules adds a unique rule code
   Failure/Error: new_rule[:rule_code] = count
     #<Double (anonymous)> received unexpected message :[]= with (:rule_code, 1)
   # ./lib/Promotional_Rules.rb:21:in `add_rule_code'
   # ./spec/promotional_rules_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I sure its a simple fix but i cant figure it out despite googling etc. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Does the error point to any line in particular?

Comment: Make sure that `new_rule` is what you think it is.  My guess is that it's not

Comment: The final line in the method, "new_rule[:rule_code] = count"  from the line in the test "rules.add_rule_code item_rule"

Comment: when i "p" new rule at the top of the method it gives me "#<Double (anonymous)>"

Comment: In add_rule, does it have all the expected values? `rule_type`? `item_code`? etc?

Comment: if i do the following at the top of the method:
 " p new_rule.rule_type
  p new_rule.item_code
  p new_rule.number_of_items
  p new_rule.new_item_price"

  i get:
"
  "item"
1
2
8.5 "

Comment: Try `new_rule.rule_code = count`

Comment: it gives the same error

Answer (score 18):

You are calling `new_rule[:rule_code]` but the double does not respond to `:[]`.

One way you can make it work is:

`allow(new_rule).to receive(:[])`

See [RSpec Mocks Method Stubs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#method-stubs).

I don't know why you are using a double. I think you might want to use a factory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, i just tried that and a few other combinations but had no luck. I am fairly new to this and am not familiar with factories and factory girl. Can you lend any more advice? Thanks

Comment: Here is the Factory Girl docs: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#method-stubs. But you don't really need a Factory. You can do `item_rule = ItemRule.new( ... )`.

Comment: It seems that you may want to learn more about RSpec. Here's a tutorial: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-rspec . I suggest you go through a few tutorials and then come back to your project. Also, writing model specs is a great way to learn.